# Connecting a device via Bluetooth not working

Tags: android, bluetooth

developed app for RGB light via Bluetooth.Now am trying to configure the device using one option search the devices got configured once am planning to do operate on/off was not working.

device already in on mode still it is showing please power on the device

can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Error:
Please power on the device
waiting for acknowledgement

```
 adapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(areaList);

public class CardViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        public List<Area> mDataset;

        public CardViewDataAdapter(List<Area> areaListItems) {
            mDataset = areaListItems;
        }

        public void updateAreaList(List<Area> areaListItems) {
            mDataset = areaListItems;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                             int viewType) {
            // create a new view
            View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    com.havells.havellssmart.R.layout.area_row, null);

            // create ViewHolder

            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
            return (ViewHolder) viewHolder;
       /* ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            try {
                final Area area = mDataset.get(position);
                holder.areaName.setText(area.getName());
                selectedPosition = SharedUtils.getInteger(getApplicationContext(), Constant.SELECTED_POSITION);
                //recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(selectedPosition);
                String areaImageName = area.getImageName();
                holder.areaImage.setImageDrawable(null);
                if (position == selectedPosition) {

                    byte[] byteImage = area.getImageInByte();
                    if (byteImage != null && byteImage.length > 0) {
                        areaEditButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 8;


                        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage, 0, byteImage.length);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage, 0, byteImage.length, options);
                        // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(byteImage, 0, byteImage.length);
                        ivAreaPhoto.setBackgroundResource(0);
                        ivAreaPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        holder.areaImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    /*    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                            bitmap.recycle();
                            bitmap = null;
                        }*/

                    } else {
                        areaEditButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        String imageUri = "@drawable/" + areaImageName.replace("unselected", "selected");
                        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(imageUri, null, getPackageName());
                        if (imageResource != 0) {
                            Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                            holder.areaImage.setImageDrawable(res);
                        }

                    }



           /*     String imageUri = "@drawable/" + areaImageName.replace("unselected", "selected");
                int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(imageUri, null, getPackageName());
                if (imageResource != 0) {
                    Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                    holder.areaImage.setImageDrawable(res);
                } else {
                    if (byteImage != null && byteImage.length > 0) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage, 0, byteImage.length);
                        holder.areaImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }*/
                    devicesInArea = dbManager.getDevicesInArea(area.getAreaID());

                    if(devicesInArea.size()==0) {
                        noDeviceText.setText("No devices in this area");
                        noDeviceText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    } else {
                        noDeviceText.setText("");
                    }

                    deviceStateInAreaList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (final Device device : devicesInArea) {

                        final DeviceStateInArea deviceStateInArea = new DeviceStateInArea();
                        deviceStateInArea.setDeviceId(device.getDeviceID());
                        System.out.print("Device Id:"+device.getDeviceID());
                        deviceStateInArea.setDeviceName(device.getName());
                        System.out.print("Device Name:"+device.getName());
                        deviceStateInArea.setPowerState(true);
                        deviceStateInArea.setErrorMessage("Connecting to network");

                        /*deviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_device_list_in_area_home_layout, deviceStateInAreaList);
                        lvDeviceList.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter);*/

                        deviceStateInAreaList.add(deviceStateInArea);

                    }

                    timer = new Timer();
                    MeshLibraryManager.MeshChannel channel = MeshLibraryManager.getInstance().getChannel();
                    if (channel == MeshLibraryManager.MeshChannel.BLUETOOTH) {
                            final TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                                private int counter = 0;
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    boolean uiUpdate;
                                    for (final DeviceStateInArea deviceStateInArea : deviceStateInAreaList) {
                                        uiUpdate = false;
                                        if (counter<3 && deviceStateInArea.getErrorMessage() != "") {
                                          if (MeshLibraryManager.getInstance().isChannelReady()) {
                                            PowerModelApi.getState(deviceStateInArea.getDeviceId());
                                            if(deviceStateInArea.getErrorMessage() != "Please power on the device") {
                                                deviceStateInArea.setErrorMessage("Waiting for acknowledgment");
                                                uiUpdate = true;
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                        if (counter >= 3) {
                                            if (deviceStateInArea.getErrorMessage() != "") {
                                                deviceStateInArea.setErrorMessage("Please power on the device");
                                                uiUpdate = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if(uiUpdate) {
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    deviceListAdapter.updateDevice(deviceStateInAreaList);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (counter >= 4) {
                                        cancel();
                                        timer.cancel();
                                        timer.purge();
                                    }
                                    ++counter;
                                }
                            };
                            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 2000);
                    }


                    deviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), com.havells.havellssmart.R.layout.custom_device_list_in_area_home_layout, deviceStateInAreaList);
                    lvDeviceList.setAdapter(deviceListAdapter);


                    holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#67b6d3"));
                } else {
                    holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(0);
                    byte[] byteImage = area.getImageInByte();
                    if (byteImage != null && byteImage.length > 0) {

                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 8;

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage, 0, byteImage.length, options);
                        holder.areaImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                     /*   if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                            bitmap.recycle();
                            bitmap = null;
                        }
*/
                    } else {
                        String imageUri = "@drawable/" + areaImageName;
                        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(imageUri, null, getPackageName());
                        if (imageResource != 0) {
                            Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                            holder.areaImage.setImageDrawable(res);
                        }
                    }


              /*  String imageUri = "@drawable/" + areaImageName;
                int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(imageUri, null, getPackageName());
                if (imageResource != 0) {
                    Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                    holder.areaImage.setImageDrawable(res);
                } else {
                    byte[] byteImage = area.getImageInByte();
                    if (byteImage != null && byteImage.length > 0) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage, 0, byteImage.length);
                        ivAreaPhoto.setBackgroundResource(0);
                        holder.areaImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                  *//*      ivAreaPhoto.setImageBitmap(null);
                        ivAreaPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_camera);*//*
                    }

                }*/
                }

                final Area finalArea = area;


                //  holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new RecyclerOnItemClickListener(position, monItemClickCallback));
                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        try {
                            final int areaId = mDataset.get(position).getAreaID();
                            System.out.println("position :" + position);
                            byte[] byteImage = finalArea.getImageInByte();
                            if (byteImage != null && byteImage.length > 0) {
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage, 0, byteImage.length);
                                ivAreaPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                             /*   if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                                   // bitmap.recycle();
                                    bitmap = null;
                                }*/
                            } else {
                                ivAreaPhoto.setImageBitmap(null);
                                ivAreaPhoto.setBackgroundResource(com.havells.havellssmart.R.drawable.profile_box);
                            }

                            SharedUtils.set(getApplicationContext(), Constant.SELECTED_POSITION, position);
                            // notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.getMessage();

                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: too much irrelevant code. You have to debug your app at least to find out which part of code is causing problems. Check whether you are able to establish connection, etc.

Comment: yes done with debugging

Comment: then why don't you show the desults of your debugging?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:336)
     api.MeshLibraryManager.enableBluetooth(MeshLibraryManager.java:149)

Comment: what is that .?

Comment: via bluetooth the device was showing

Comment: where was it showing?

Comment: name of the device was getting RGB7C

Comment: Please start reading my comment, please stop writing random phrases: `at com.squareup.otto.Bus.post(Bus.java:336) api.MeshLibraryManager.enableBluetooth(MeshLibraryManager.java:149)` What is this?